# Glassfish installation problems on eclipse kepler

Tags: glassfish-3, server

I am installing Glassfish 3 on eclipse kepler. But, I am getting the following problem

[image]

Why I am getting this problem?.

How can I overcome this error to install glassfish server.

Please help me.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on your screenshot the error message says that **Glassfish needs a full Java JDK and not a JRE**, like you selected.

If you have already installed a JDK choose that instead of "Default JRE".

If you didn't already install a JDK, do that and register it in your Eclipse (`Settings` -> `Java` -> `Installed JREs`).